# PreferenceFragment NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

```
public class MyPrefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyPreferenceFragment frag =  new MyPreferenceFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();

        Preference pref;
        pref = frag.findPreference("pref_gps_updates");

        pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.preference.Preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(android.preference.Preference$OnPreferenceChangeListener)' on a null object reference`

I don't understand why I get this crash or what I am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_gps_updates"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:title="@string/pref_gps_updates"
        android:summary="@string/pref_gps_updates_summary"
        android:defaultValue="60" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: frag.findPreference("pref_updates"); returns null, easy as that. It didn't find the preference. Post your preferences xml, your key is probably not existing.

Comment: Added my xml/preference.xml

Comment: You are correct I misspelled my preference in my question, upon verification there must be something else too Let me edit my question, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Preference pref;
pref = frag.findPreference("pref_updates");

pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Put this part into your **Fragment**'s `onCreate()` (**NOT** in the activities onCreate) and double check if the key `pref_updates` is used in your `xml`.

Update:

```
public class MyPrefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


            Preference pref;
            pref = findPreference("pref_gps_updates");

            pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyPreferenceFragment frag =  new MyPreferenceFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok going to try this one moment please

Comment: Hmm I don't understand sorry because I need to create this object? `MyPreferenceFragment frag =  new MyPreferenceFragment();` Can you paste the correct order in your answer please?

Answer (score 2):

In code you use

```
pref = frag.findPreference("pref_updates");
```

but in xml it says

```
android:key="pref_gps_updates"
```

change keys need to match to be found.

Comment: You are correct I misspelled my preference in my question, upon verification there must be something else too Let me edit my question, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a PreferenceChangedListener for each preference, it would be better to just have your `PreferenceFragment` implement the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` interface.

That way, no matter how many preferences you add, you won't need to add a new listener for each one, and the logic is self-contained in the `PreferenceFragment`.

It would be something like this:

```
public class MyPrefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyPreferenceFragment frag = new MyPreferenceFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();

        /* remove all of this
        Preference pref;
        pref = frag.findPreference("pref_gps_updates");
        pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        */

    }


    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
            implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

            if (key.equals("pref_gps_updates")) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, need some time to look at your example and test it.

Comment: Valid solution, and probably the best, unfortunately I can only accept one answer in stackoverflow.

Comment: @GertCuykens Sure, no problem!  I had a feeling that the accepted solution was the root cause of your issue.  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Try and move the code up before you do the fragment transaction.

```
    MyPreferenceFragment frag =  new MyPreferenceFragment();

    Preference pref;
    pref = frag.findPreference("pref_gps_updates");

    pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            return true;
        }
    });

   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();

}
```

}

Comment: This probably is also the reason for the exception, can you copy and paste the example please to be sure I understand it correctly how the order needs to be.

Comment: Unfortunately this gave me the same error, but I also think you are right and it has to do with the order of execution.